# Java. Array, save previous values

Tags: java, arrays, loops, store

Cant figure out how to do this thing. I need to store and count number of "jumps" and direction of "jump" in array. 
Console has to display something like this:

> : Jump 1, direction Left
>
> : Jump 2, direction Right

In my code below, when I print array elements,  `int jump` always equals to 0;

I tried many variations, sometimes I got (for example):

```
jump();

jump();

jump();

jump();
```

And it prints: `{0,0,0,4}` , instead of `{1,2,3,4};`

```
public class Jump {
int jump;
String direction;
Jump[] jumpArray = new Jump[100];
int storeJump;
String storeDirection;

public void jump() {
    jump++;
    if (jump > 50) {
        System.out.println("need a rest");
        return;
    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < jumpArray.length; i++) {
            jumpArray[i] = new Jump();
        }
    }
    jumpArray[jump].storeJump = jump;
    jumpArray[jump].storeDirection = direction;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Jump jumper = new Jump();
    jumper.jump();
    jumper.jump();

    for (int i = 0; i < jumper.jump; i++) {
        System.out.println(jumper.jumpArray[i].jump);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: In your `jump()` method, you are replacing all `Jump` objects each time : `jumpArray[i] = new Jump();` , that is probably not what you want .

Comment: you´re only printing the elements from `jumpArray` which is a `Jump[]`. within `Jump#jump()` you repeadiatly reinitialize the array for each call of the `Jump#jump` call, and in the end store the incremented value of `jump` inside `Jump#storejump`. But in the end you´re printing `jumpArray[i].jump`, as you never assign values to it within the method, will allways be `0`. Additionally there are some more design flaws making it more difficult than it probably should be

Comment: If I may ask that Question: Why has the class Jump an Array of itself jumpArray as a field? That seems a weird design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code below will solve your problem, but I think You should improve your code.

```
int jump;
String direction;
Jump[] jumpArray = new Jump[100];
int storeJump;
String storeDirection;

public void jumping() {
    jump++;
    if (jump > 50) {
        System.out.println("need a rest");
        return;
    } else {
        jumpArray[jump] = new Jump();
    }
    jumpArray[jump].storeJump = jump;
    jumpArray[jump].storeDirection = direction;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Jump jumper = new Jump();
    jumper.jumping();
    jumper.jumping();

    Set<Jump> mySet = new HashSet<Jump>(Arrays.asList(jumper.jumpArray));

    for (int i = 1; i < mySet.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(jumper.jumpArray[i].storeJump);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much!  You really helped me a lot!  Im so mad at me right now, because I wrote code similar like yours(just without HashSet) , and always got NullPointerException, and now I saw int i=1; Thats all I had to do, because jump++ increments, and array[0] =null, right? and array[1]=value. And it came to my mind just when I studied your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make more sense to move the `jumpArray` into `main()`:

```
public class Jump {
    String direction;
    //int storeJump;   Not sure what this is for
    //String storeDirection;    Or this

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return direction;
    }

    // Static function that creates an initializes a Jump object
    public static Jump jump(String direction) {
        Jump jump = new Jump();
        jump.direction = direction;
        return jump;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Jump[] jumpArray = new Jump[100];
        int numJumps = 0;

        // A list of directions for testing
        String [] path = new String[]{"north", "south", "east", "west"};

        // Create a bunch of jumps
        for (String dir : path) {
            if (numJumps > 50) {
                System.out.println("need a rest");
                break;
            }
            // Create a new jump and add to the array
            jumpArray[numJumps++] = Jump.jump(dir);
        }

        // Print the jumps
        for (int i = 0; i < numJumps; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + jumpArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```